# Using built in socket with NodeJS application

Tags: node.js, sockets

I wave a working NodeJS application that properly uses FFMPEG for video conversion. I haven't had much luck using socket.io so instead I want to the native socket class in Node. This is my node app so far. 
Specifically I need to send a socket event or message in the '**on('end', function()**'

```
var ffmpeg =  require('./lib/fluent-ffmpeg');

var express = require('express'),
    multer  = require('multer');
var app = express();

//auto save file to uploads folder
app.use(multer({ dest: './uploads/'}))
var temp;

app.post('/', function (req, res) {
    console.log(req.body); //contains the variables
    console.log("req.files ="+ req.files); //contains the file references

console.log("req.files.Filedata.path ="+ req.files.Filedata.path ); 

temp=req.files.Filedata.path;
console.log("temp ="+temp);


// make sure you set the correct path to your video file
var proc = ffmpeg('./'+temp)

  // set audio bitrate
  .audioBitrate('128k')
  // set audio codec
  .audioCodec('libmp3lame')

  // set output format to force
  .format('avi')
  // setup event handlers
  .on('end', function() {
    console.log('file has been converted succesfully');
  })
  .on('error', function(err) {
    console.log('an error happened: ' + err.message);
  })
  // save to file
  .save('./converted/converted.avi');
    res.send('Thank you for uploading!');

});

app.listen(8080);
```

Comment: You're not using a socket in your application... and what is on the other end that you're trying to communicate with?  Sockets are just network connections in this context, and not something you can use to communicate with web browsers, which is what it looks like you are trying to do.

Comment: no I'm not communicating with a web browser, but rather a desktop (AIR) application.